# Permission Denied Error when trying to install packages in a directory I have group permissions to

Tags: package-management, permissions

I have a Linux machine where my user (non-root) user is assigned the group `user_group`.
I am using a special package manager called [spack](https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and would like to use it in a directory where only root users have write and execute permissions. I installed it there using sudo and then added those modifications to the directory itself:

```
sudo chgrp -R user_group spack/
sudo chmod -R +rwx spack/
```

Now I am able to use this package-manager to install some packages. for other packages however, it returns the following error:

```
...

==> Installing nasm-2.15.05-xfzo4rjbzpriugrjmr7ecszho4jowvku
==> No binary for nasm-2.15.05-xfzo4rjbzpriugrjmr7ecszho4jowvku found: installin                                                                                                                                                             g from source
==> Fetching https://mirror.spack.io/_source-cache/archive/3c/3caf6729c1073bf966                                                                                                                                                             29b57cee31eeb54f4f8129b01902c73428836550b30a3f.tar.xz
==> Error: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/etc/spack/                                                                                                                                                             var/spack/cache/_source-cache/archive/3c/3caf6729c1073bf96629b57cee31eeb54f4f812                                                                                                                                                             9b01902c73428836550b30a3f.tar.xz'

/usr/local/etc/spack/lib/spack/spack/package.py:1401, in do_fetch:
       1398
       1399        if checksum and self.version in self.versions:
       1400            self.stage.check()
  >>   1401
       1402        self.stage.cache_local()
       1403
       1404        for patch in self.spec.patches:

...
```

My guess is that this newly created folder does not yet have the permissions I have granted all the other already present files. Is there any way I can prevent this from happening? How can I still download and install packages in this situation?

Comment: @steeldriver you are right, but this didn't change anything about the same error occuring.